# ElasticSearch delete index data without API

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an issue with my index and on ES startup i get an

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException -- tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value
```

thus ES is not starting at all...

The data i have is of no importance, is there a way to manually delete the index all together (mapping and data) ? Or if not just update the index mapping?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that's a good idea but you can try deleting 'indices' folder - this will delete all the indices so be careful.

I have 2 elasticsearch clusters one with 3 indexes and other is empty so the folder structure is looking like this,

1. the one with 3 indexes,

   ls "the data directory path from elasticsearch.yml"/nodes/0/indices

11RicU32QMK1r5Hu89ktKg  FViegU6eTWOti8_bMQSMww  YVw4MImcSlCeM5lqWlXW3w

As you can see the index names are obfuscated.

2. the one with no indexes,

   ls "the data directory path from elasticsearch.yml"/nodes/0/

   node.lock  _state

second one has no 'indices' folder.

HTH.

Comment: @user3392362 did my answer help you? or you ended up using some other approach?